# Major and minor creation as crafting materials

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

Can you use major and minor creation as components to craft items, and if you can what happens to the components used? Do they disappear while part of said crafted item?

E.g.: I conjure up a black lotus and craft it into black lotus extract poison.

Comment: [Highly related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35739/15469).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, assuming you've created something with a sufficient duration to use crafting on (which is unlikely but possible).  The crafted item would disappear/be ruined (depending on whether it's composed entirely or partially of the created item) at the end of the duration, as you'd expect.  A black lotus extract poison, assuming you could make it inside of the 2 hours/level duration, would disappear entirely at the end of the duration.