# If you cast True Polymorph on matter made with the Creation spell will the creature disappear after the duration of Creation ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, polymorph

Cast creation to make vegetables that last a day, then cast true polymorph to make a dwarf from the vegetables, does the Creature disappear after a day? It says that if you use the matter created by Creation as a component the spell fails but True Polymorph doesn't use the target as a component.

Comment: Related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35739/51849 (my personal guess is the answer would be the same)

Comment: It half answers, I was hoping for something other than "Up to the DM" but so much is actually up the the DM that it is a very common answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It eventually disappears

*Creation* is a spell with a duration and anything it creates only exists for that duration.

*True polymorph* transforms its target, but it does not prevent its target from ceacing to exist. Hence, when the duration of *creation* ends, the created object ceases to exist and *true polymorph* looses its target.

Fortunatelly, there is no lack of nonmagical objects to target with *true polymorph*.

#### *True polymorph* and *creation* might be incompatible

*True polymorph* cannot target magical objects. *Creation* does not specify whether the object it creates is magical or not, but it is made of "whisps of shadow" and only exists for the duration, so it would be entirely reasonable (if not likely) for a DM to rule that the object is magical.